# submitting form via email with dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, asp.net, email

Thank you in advance.

The code now works exactly as I need it too but I'm not sure how to go about passing each new line to my .asp mail handler if all the input names are the same.  Where exactly in my code would I index the input boxes so that I can call them uniquely during submission and email themwith .asp mail handler?

Thank you to the stackoverflow community for helping me troubleshoot the code I've written thus far!

HTML

```
<form role="form" action="/wohoo" method="POST">
    <label>Item</label>
    <div class="catalog-fieldset">
        <div class="catalog-wrapper">
            <div class="catalog-items">
                <ul>
                    <li>Quantity:
                        <input type="text" size="5" name="Qty[]">
                    </li>
                    <li>Width:
                        <input type="text" size="5" name="Width[]">
                    </li>
                    <li>Height:
                        <input type="text" size="5" name="Height[]">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="remove-line">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="add-field">Add More...</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 0 5px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.remove-line {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I have this code set up http://jsfiddle.net/KeithDickens/afqh4a5o/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var x = 1; //initlal text box count    

$('.catalog-fieldset').each(function () {
    var $wrapper = $('.catalog-wrapper', this);

    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment        
            $('.catalog-items:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
        }
    });
    $('.catalog-items .remove-line', $wrapper).click(function () {
        x = x - 1; //initlal text box count    
        if ($('.catalog-items', $wrapper).length > 1) $(this).parent('.catalog-items').remove();
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Your question actually has nothing to do with "submitting form via email" but rather is just how to "iterate child controls" which you are already doing via $('.catalog-fieldset').each. Knowing the position of each input you can reference them via their index. That said you're going about it in an outside -in fashion, by using controls to build data structure. You might to check out something like Knockout.js whereby you setup the viewmodel first such that UI is driven from model.

Comment: I am definitely going to investigate Knockout.  But are you saying that there is no way to accomplish what I need based on my code?  There is no way to pass the value of those dynamically created fields on to my asp mail file by input name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading values given your current setup would simply be based on position. This is terribly brittle since if you change the position you break the code but if you were to add a

```
<button type="button" class="summarise">Summarise</button>
```

beneath your existing Add More button and swap out your javascript for what's below it should give you more than a start. Validation etc will need to be applied.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count    

    function LineItemViewModel() {
       var self = this;
       self.Qty = 0;
       self.Width = 0;
       self.Height = 0;
    }

    function CollectionViewModel() {
      var self = this;
      self.Items = [];
    }
    var collection = new CollectionViewModel();

    $('.catalog-fieldset').each(function () {
        var $wrapper = $('.catalog-wrapper', this);

        $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment        
                $('.catalog-items:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
            }
        });

       $(".summarise", $(this)).click(function (e) {
           var txts = $('.catalog-fieldset input[type=text]');
           var item = new LineItemViewModel();
           txts.each(function () {
               switch($(this).attr("name")){
                   case "Qty[]":
                      item.Qty = $(this).val();
                      break;
                  case "Width[]":
                     item.Width = $(this).val();
                     break;
                  case "Height[]":
                     item.Height = $(this).val();
                     collection.Items.push(item);
                     item = new LineItemViewModel();
                     break;        
                }
             });
             alert(collection.Items.length);
         });

        $('.catalog-items .remove-line', $wrapper).click(function () {
            x = x - 1; //initlal text box count    
            if ($('.catalog-items', $wrapper).length > 1) $(this).parent('.catalog-items').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

There are cleaner / shorter / more concise ways to do the above but this way should be very self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I like this path much better, but in actuality, I'm scrapping the page and starting sometime completely new.  For one, I'm going back the beginning and reupping my JavaScript skills which were top notch a decade ago.  But, coding is not like riding a bike, use it or lose it.